# CSS IE hover menu disapears after initial mouse over

Tags: css

When I roll over the drop down menus on my site in internet explorer the first time I roll on it drops down no problem, but if I roll off then roll back over with my mouse a very small white box is there but the links are gone, Ive searched everywhere but cannot find an answer. Below is my code:

```
.natlmenu
{
position:absolute;
width:980px;
text-align:left;
z-index:300;
top:121px;
margin-left:0px;
}

.natlmenu a, .natlmenu a:hover, .natlmenu a:visited, .natlmenu a:active
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
}

.natlmenu .mapsection
{
}

.natlmenu .mapsectionhead
{

font-size:16px;
height:36px;
padding:10px 15px 0 12px;

}

.natlmenu .mapsection:hover .mapsectionhead
{
background-color:White;

}

.natlmenu .mapsection:hover a, .natlmenu .mapsection:hover a:active, .natlmenu .mapsection:hover 
a:visited
{
color:#002347;
text-decoration:none;
}

.natlmenu .mapsection:hover a:hover
{
color:#002347;
text-decoration:underline;

}

.natlmenu .mapsection table
{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:49px;
left:0px;
background-color:#ffffff;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
border-left: 3px #002347 solid;
border-bottom: 3px #002347 solid;
border-right: 3px #002347 solid;

}

.natlmenu .mapsection:hover table
{
display:block;
}


.natlmenu .mapsection table td
{
display:inline-table;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding: 9px 17px 7px 17px;
box-shadow:none;
width:100px;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
vertical-align:top;
}

.natlmenu .mapsection table td ul
{
box-shadow:block;
display:block;
position:static;
padding:0px 0 0 0;
margin:9px 0 0 0;
border:0px;
}

.natlmenu .mapsection table td ul li
{
display:block;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
padding:0;
margin:0;
padding: 0 0 7px 2px;
}
```

Comment: Please also provide your relevant HTML, or a fiddle so we can help you.

Comment: This implies that you're using tables for your menus. Bad choice.